# Keypress To Simulate A Button Click in C#

Tags: c#, click, keypress, simulate

Ok, so I'm in the process of making a Tic-Tac-Toe game to help me learn C#.
I'm attempting to add a bit of functionality to it, so I want people to be able to use the NumPad on a computer to simulate clicking the buttons.

Here is what I have but when I use the NumPad the buttons don't click. 
Can any of you see a reason as to why?

```
    //===============================
    // start NumPad Simulate Clicks
    //   NumPad  MyButtons
    //   7 8 9   1 2 3
    //   4 5 6   4 5 6 
    //   1 2 3   7 8 9
    //===============================
    public void myControl_NumPad7(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.NumPad7)
        {
            button1_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
    public void myControl_NumPad8(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.NumPad8)
        {
            button2_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
    public void myControl_NumPad9(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.NumPad9)
        {
            button3_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
    public void myControl_NumPad4(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.NumPad4)
        {
            button4_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
    public void myControl_NumPad5(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.NumPad5)
        {
            button5_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
    public void myControl_NumPad6(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.NumPad6)
        {
            button6_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
    public void myControl_NumPad1(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.NumPad1)
        {
            button7_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
    public void myControl_NumPad2(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.NumPad2)
        {
            button8_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
    public void myControl_NumPad3(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.NumPad3)
        {
            button9_Click(null, null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**
*Noticed that I have to be clearer about what I mean...*

From the code you posted I suspect you have 9 controls you added your key-events to. These controls will only receive key-events when they are focused.

To handle keys globally for the form, you have to set `Form.KeyPreview` to `true`. Also, I'd not handle the keys the way you do, but add a `Form.KeyDown` event and write something like:

```
switch (e.KeyCode)
{
    case Keys.NumPad9:
        e.Handled = true;
        button3.PerformClick();
        break;
    case Keys.NumPad8:
        e.Handled = true;
        button2.PerformClick();
        break;
    // And so on
}
```

This will handle the NumPad-Keys within the form - you can then remove all the event handlers you posted in your question.

To programatically "click" a button, you should use the `Button.PerformClick()` method, as more than one event handler may be added to the click event, which would not be called otherwise.

**EDIT 2**
Syntax for the `switch`-statement was invalid. Of course every "case" must start with the `case` keyword... Now it should work.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for but I can't figure out where to put your code. I set KeyPreview = true; when Form1 initializes after that I just get stuck.

Comment: Just set it in the form's properties (Properties window). In the Properties window change the view to the events-section, look for the KeyDown-event and double click that item. This adds a new event Form_KeyDown to your code, where you put my code. Alternatively, go to the form's source code and type "override" - from the Code Insight window, select the "OnKeyDown" method. A stub is generated for you. After the "base.OnKeyDown" line, add my code.

Comment: I just tried that and I'm afraid it still doesn't work.

I get a couple errors dwindled down from when I replaced the : with ;

The main ones being.
No enclosing loop of which to break or continue(these are from break;)

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement. (x3) (I get this on the Keys.NumPad and on the closing bracket of switch.

Comment: Oops, sorry, wrong syntax for the switch statement in my sample. I'll update my reply.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  `button1.PerformClick();` for every button to invoke event correctly, here's [info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick.aspx).