# Activate a button Process via custom KeyPress

Tags: c#, button

Basically in a C# Windows Form Application I am working on I have 2 buttons I press `button1` and `button2`.

How do I make it when I press `2 custom keys` simultaneously(*eg.* <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) the program does the steps coded for `button1`? Keeping in mind that the window might not be active.

I have looked at this: [Keypress To Simulate A Button Click in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807483/keypress-to-simulate-a-button-click-in-c-sharp) but I don't think this would work if the window isn't active, and its also only one button pressed not two.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400113/best-way-to-implement-keyboard-shortcuts-in-winforms

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegisterHotKeys and global keyboard hooks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563849/registerhotkeys-and-global-keyboard-hooks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Form KeyUp Event` and the Properties is `KeyPressPreview = true` you can achieve this task.

```
   private void Form_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.L && e.Control)
       {
                yourButton.PerformClick();
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

**or**

if you want in `Keypress Event`

```
private void Form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.L)
    {
            yourButton.PerformClick();
            e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I realized that the OP want to the `keypress Event` from his statement *"but I don't think this would work if the window isn't active"*

You probably must check this

[How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804)

Comment: So is their a shorter way of doing this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804 ?

Comment: as you notice from the link example, is easy to understand. good luck `:)`

Answer (score 0):

If you precede any character in the button text with &, and keep UseMnemonic to true,. the alt+character will serve as shortcut key.

For example, in your case change the text of the buttons to **button&1** and **button&2** respectively. Keep **UserMnemonic = true**. Now if you press **alt+1** then button1 will be pressed and if you press **alt+2**, button2 will be pressed.

Also 1 and 2 respectively will be underlined.

Hope that helps.